# onkeyup, onkeydown events not firing for SPAN element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, html

I've defined the following two span elements:
1)  element inside a contenteditable div. 
2)  contenteditable element.

So far, I can't get the onkey events to fire for my first case ().
For the second one () which is not inside a contenteditable div, these events fire fine.

Does anybody knows why?

Here's the example code:

```
<div id='editor' contenteditable>
div contents...
<span id='span1' style="background-color:red"  onkeyup='alert("span1 keyup");' onkeypress='alert("span1 keypress");' onkeydown='alert("span1 keydown");'>Hello</span>
</div>

<span contenteditable id='span2' style="background-color:yellow" onkeyup='alert("span2 keyup");' onkeypress='alert("span2 keypress");' onkeydown='alert("span2 keydown");'>World</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nr9HG/

Comment: I think because span1 is not directly contenteditable so it will not fire any event

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it seems to work if you put your editable span inside another non-editable span :

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">div contents...
    <span contenteditable="false>
        <span id='span1' contenteditable="true" style="background-color:red"  onkeyup='alert("span1 keyup");' onkeypress='alert("span1 keypress");' onkeydown='alert("span1 keydown");'>Hello</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

You will be able to catch keydown/keyup events both on the editor div AND in your span1.

You need the inner span to have the focus to catch keydown events coming from it. Use the DOM method .focus() to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `span1` is not a contenteditable so it will not fire any event.

You can set contenteditable on child too, but it will not fired because the wrapping contenteditable div `editor` catch the events before the inner span, so they are not fired on the child `span1`.

So you can change your code in:

```
<div id='editor' contenteditable="false">div contents...
<span id='span1' contenteditable="true" style="background-color:red"  onkeyup='alert("span1 keyup");' onkeypress='alert("span1 keypress");' onkeydown='alert("span1 keydown");'>Hello</span>

</div>
<span contenteditable="true" id='span2' style="background-color:yellow" onkeyup='alert("span2 keyup");' onkeypress='alert("span2 keypress");' onkeydown='alert("span2 keydown");'>World</span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/U8wnK/

Side note: I think it's better to explicit the boolean value of contenteditable in your markup

Comment: Thx Irvin... but what if I need div "editor" to be contenteditable as well? 
My application uses div as a container were the user can type any text, and it does some formatting to certain keywords as it finds it. For instance: it sets the font color to yellow to the "yellow" word when it was typed. I need to get notified when "yellow" word has changed (i.e. the user deleted letter "w") to update the color as necessary.
So, how can I get notified about keypress/keyup/keydown on span element considering that its container needs to be contenteditable?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the new `window.getSelection()` API through which you could access the leaf-most node that is part of your current selection. I.e:

```
<div contenteditable onkeyup="getTarget">
   <span id="1">One</span>
   <span id="2">Two</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function getTarget(ev) {
   const selection = window.getSelection();
   // assuming your cursor is over "One"
   console.log(selection.baseNode.parentNode) // <span id="1"></span>
}
```

May or may not meet your requirements.