# Key event binding at table level

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 tables on 1 page. I would like the user to be able to click the table and then use the arrow keys to navigate to previous and next. The only way I have been able to get the keyup events to fire in all browsers is by attaching them directly to the 'document'. I have wired up an event to add a 'grid-focused' class to the grid that is in focus and I tried using that as the selector on my events but I cannot get any event action then.

Event Binding

```
function attachInitEvents() {
    if ($self.config.pageHotKeysEnabled) {
        var keyNav = function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 37 && paging.hasPrevious) { // left
                $self._log.info('Left arrow key pressed.');
                fetchData('prev');
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 39 && paging.hasNext) { //right
                $self._log.info('Right arrow key pressed.');
                fetchData('next');
            }
        }
        var $doc = $(document);

        // hot key support
        $doc.off('keyup');
        $doc.on('keyup', keyNav);
    }
}
```

I am having another issue, where I am doing $doc.off('keyup'). I think this is part of the problem as it is unbinding all keyup events, what I really want is for it to just unbind the event I am trying to attach if it exists. In jQuery docs it technically says I should be using $doc.off('keyup', keyNav); to unbind it, but it does not unbind the event and I get multiples of it.

So core questions are,

1. Can I trigger a KeyUp event without binding to the document and can I do it from the table level?
2. How can I properly make sure I am not rebinding over and over again? Now, if this page has 2 tables, I guess I would expect there
   to be 2 events one for each table and then the .grid-focused class
   would be what allows the event to trigger or not?

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93fp293w/

Basically, I have no input boxes it is just spans, I am basically making it easier for them to page through all the data by just using the arrow keys. I believe the fiddler is pretty accurate to the situation. I feel what I am asking is not possible since I wont have an actual control in focus and if that is the case I can accept that but I guess I am hoping there is a work around.

Comment: 1. You can bind `.keyUp()` to anything but it really only makes sense to bind it to something that requires keyboard interaction.

2. It sounds like you want to turn off event bubbling. Read up on the `e.stopPropagation()` method and see if it will suit your needs.

Comment: i might be talking nonsense, but can't you do this ? this is a fiddle i was trying out .... http://jsfiddle.net/puneethp/qfpyeydg/

Comment: Thank you Darth, I wasn't even sure how to begin to create a fiddle for what I was asking. I have update my question using your fiddle to give a better idea of whats going on.

Comment: So i do have a input box I am using as a page jump box, I have decided that will probably be the best place to attach the event. I wanted it to work on the page in general but this may make more sense anyways.

Comment: Hi @Tony there is a reason why span won't just work, more on that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836477/onkeyup-onkeydown-events-not-firing-for-span-element. but i did what they have told me to i.e. make span content editable .. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/puneethp/qfpyeydg/2/

Comment: @DarthCoder, thank you for putting so much effort into this. I see my initial goal was flawed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with attaching keyup is that, the parent div has to be mutable(contenteditable). else you have to attach to the document.

I have updated fiddle, might be a hack let me know if this works for you ?

http://jsfiddle.net/puneethp/qfpyeydg/3/

```
$(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
e.target = $(".focus")[0];
..
}
```

if you have only one column focused at a time, my previous fiddle will still work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I assumed an element had to be able to get focus but I was hoping a class could be used as a hack. Nice fiddler example. In the end I ended up just tying the event to the jump box and its working good. Appreciate the time you spent on this :)

Comment: So I just went back and looked at the fiddle, I didn't realize you removed the editable text. This actually is brilliant, I may back track when I have a moment and utilize your code for the functionality because I am not liking how it works using the jump box. Great job!