# Click event on a span inside an iframe does not fire jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a span inside an iframe but when I add the click event, it does not fire.

I tried the solution on this thread but it doesn't work for me: [onkeyup, onkeydown events not firing for SPAN element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836477/onkeyup-onkeydown-events-not-firing-for-span-element)

Is it that click events on elements in iframe cannot be triggered? Or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: If the `src` of the iframe is on a different domain to the parent window then you cannot access it's contents due to the security restrictions in place.

Answer (score 0):

It can work if the page inside the iframe is on the same domain.

On the page inside the iframe you can use something like this:

```
<span onclick="parent.HandleChildClick('test')">My content</span>
```

And on the page containing the iframe just a normal Javascript function.

```
function HandleChildClick(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```