# How to call function in ng-repeat with key press enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call `selectedDay()` function on entering key press.

```html
<div class="week" ng-repeat="week in weeks" 
                  arrow-selector='{"row":{{weeks.length}}, "col":7}'>
  <span class="day fontSize" >{{week.name}}</span>
  <span class="day" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flipFlop"  
        ng-class="{'selectedBox':$index == selectedCol && $parent.$index ==  selectedRow }" 
        ng-click="selectedDay(day,week.name)"
        ng-repeat="day in week.days"
        style="overflow:auto; line-height:15px !important;" focus-me="true" id="selectedDay"> 
    
    <span>{{day.number}}</span>
    <span class="chip" ng-repeat="ct in day.timeLog" ng-if="day.timeLog.length">{{ ct.Shift }} : {{ ct.Hours }}hr</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your code on fiddle?

Comment: Hi Laxmikant what exactly you looking for .. I will explain actually with ng-click i can able to call selectedDay(day, week.name) but I need an alternate way when I hit enter key the function selectedDay(day, week.name) need to be called.

Comment: can you add the controller code ?

Comment: I have made a JS Fiddle for your convenience.
just go through the below link and find out how **ng-keydown**works for **ng-repeat** by calling a particular function on keypress of **ENTER** key.

    https://jsfiddle.net/72sbjcno/9/

Comment: Thanks, Niraj but you have written ng-keypress on body element but I need this inside ng-repeat element in a span tag please help related to this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836477/onkeyup-onkeydown-events-not-firing-for-span-element